# Return command in Ruby Switch?

Tags: ruby, switch-statement, return-value

I would like to return a value from my Case statement and I need to execute more than a single line of code so "then" doesn't work for me. Using Return exits the function that the Case statement is in. Is there a keyword that will help my code clearly imply what I am returning without just putting a value on the last line?

```
complexity = case(scale)
  when "gtp"
     x = [various lines of code]
     x = [various lines of code]
     10
  when "preSi"
     x = [various lines of code]
     x = [various lines of code]
     30
  when "postSi"    
     x = [various lines of code]
     x = [various lines of code]
     40
  else
     error"Scale not recognized: #{scale.to_s}"
  end
```

Comment: Then why not just use `return` keyword with whatever/wherever you are returning something?

Comment: "return" exits the function I am using this case statement in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on what happens in *various lines of code*, you could refactor it into several methods:

```
complexity = case(scale)
  when 'gtp'   then gtp_complexity
  when 'preSi' then preSi_complexity
  ...
end

# and elsewhere...
def gtp_complexity
  x = [various lines of code]
  x = [various lines of code]
  10
end
...
```

Of course, once you have this you can ditch the `case` in favor of a Hash of lambdas:

```
complexities = {
  'gtp' => lambda { ... },
  ...
}
complexities.default_proc = lambda do |h, scale|
  lambda { error "Scale not recognized: #{scale}" }
end

complexity = complexities[scale].call
```

Or if you like the methods better, use a Hash of methods:

```
complexities = {
  'gtp' => method(:gtp_complexity),
  ...
}
complexities.default_proc = lambda do |h, scale|
  lambda { error "Scale not recognized: #{scale}" }
end

complexity = complexities[scale].call
```

or use the instance itself as your lookup table and whitelist:

```
complexity = if(respond_to?("#{scale}_complexity"))
  send("#{scale}_complexity")
else
  error "Scale not recognized: #{scale}"
end
```

Comment: I picked your answer not because I will use your suggestion on this particular code, but because you gave me some great examples of how to better code the Ruby way. Very creative, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

No there is not a keyword to explicitly label the returned value from a `case` statement in Ruby.

You can explicitly assign to the variable, you are already doing that with `x`, and presumably using that local variable further down, it's no different:

```
  case(scale)
  when "gtp"
     x = [various lines of code]
     x = [various lines of code]
     complexity = 10
  when "preSi"
     x = [various lines of code]
     x = [various lines of code]
     complexity = 30
  when "postSi"    
     x = [various lines of code]
     x = [various lines of code]
     complexity = 40
  else
     error "Scale not recognized: #{scale.to_s}"
  end
```

If that doesn't work for you, then other constructs are available that might avoid using `case` at all, or you could move your multi-line constructs into other methods or  even a class that holds `x` and `complexity`. Whether or not this could improve your code is more a subject for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - it will depend on higher level things, such as whether your scale categories appear elsewhere.

Comment: This makes sense, because this case expression isn't a pure expression. It's kind of weird to have it both set variables and yield a value. This way you're only setting variables, which is more clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this suggestion. Looks better, than what I have.